# store summary output in a list of tables or matrix

Tags: r

How to read the following vector "c" of strings into a list of tables? Which way is the shortest read.table strsplit? e.g. I cant see how to read the table *Edit:c[4:6]* a[4:6] in one command.

```
require(car)
m<-matrix(rnorm(16),4,4,byrow=T)
a<-Anova(lm(m~1),type=3,idata=data.frame(treatment=factor(1:4)),idesign=~treatment)
c<-capture.output(summary(a,multivariate=F))
c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns lines 4:6

```
 c[4:6]
```

Now if you wanted to parse this I would do it in two steps. First on the column values from rows 5:6 and then add back the names.

```
> vals <- read.table(text=c[5:6])
> txt <- "                \t    SS\t num Df\t  Error SS\t den Df\t       F\t  Pr(>F)"
> names(vals) <- names(read.delim(text=txt))
> vals
            X         SS num.Df  Error.SS den.Df       F  Pr..F.
1 (Intercept) 0.57613392      1 0.4219563      3 4.09616 0.13614
2   treatment 1.85936442      3 8.2899759      9 0.67287 0.58996
```

Comment: I was also trying sth. like this and got problems e.g. with the blank between"< 2e-16" and different number of elements per line because of "***" and "< 2e-16".
`

Comment: An alternative would be to use `read.fwf`, but it would be less 'automatic ' because you would need to first print the output and then calculate the spacing..

Comment: I'm thinking that @adibender's approach might be better.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT -- 
you could look at the source code of the `summary` function and calculate the quantities required by yourself

```
getAnywhere(summary.Anova.mlm)
```

The original idea seems not to work.

```
c2 <- summary(a)
# find out what 'properties' the summary object has
# turns out, it is just the Anova object
class(c2) <- "list"
names(c2)
```

This returns

```
 [1] "SSP"        "SSPE"       "P"          "df"         "error.df"  
 [6] "terms"      "repeated"   "type"       "test"       "idata"     
[11] "idesign"    "icontrasts" "imatrix"    "singular"
```

and we can get access them

```
c2$SSP
c2$SSPE
```

It seems not a good idea to use R internal `c` function as a variable name

Comment: Iam not sure if I got you, I think c2 is not what you imagine, str(c2) shows you the interesting values are not listed.

Comment: Which are the interesting values?

Comment: Do you not see that c shows different table than your c2? _It seems not a good idea to use R internal c function as a variable name_ sry I used it only for this short example.

Comment: _EDIT -- you could look at the source code of the summary function and calculate the quantities required by yourself_ 
that is a good solution, I mentioned below, thx to both of you.